# bluetooth tools - please clarify terminology / tools used

Tags: bluetooth

Using Ubuntu 16.04.7
On desktop top menu bar I have a bluetooth icon, basically an access to "System Setting".
What is the actual name of application giving the submenu options?
I found "blueman is GTK application..."

I also found "blueman / bluetooth manager" and a note
"you can install blueman and it will replace blueman from initial install"

Then there is "bluetoothctl"...

Questions

1. What runs the desktop menu AFTER install ?
   Name of the app and possibly a source code reference.
2. What would be the advantage to install this "blueman (?) " AFTER installation of OS?
   Name of the app and possibly a source code reference.
3. How does "bluetoothctl" fits in the scheme of things?
   There are five repositories of "bluetoothctl"!
   "Who is on first ?" AKA  which one is most reliable?

**I am after ANY source code which does "..delete device from list.."**

Minor greenhorn inquiry
In Linux world
what are differences between

tool
package
application

would be nice to refer to the above bluetooth question.

Appreciate any replies.

Cheers

Comment: The question is very unclear. Can you elaborate "I also found "blueman / bluetooth manager" and a note "you can install blueman and it will replace blueman from initial install"? And "There are five repositories of "bluetoothctl"!

Comment: `blueman` is a program for BT settings. `bluetoothctl` is a service. It seems that you need some basic knowledge of how linux systems work.